# How to edit every alert in ionic, and not one by one?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, alert, edit, title

I want my webapp (compiled with ionic) to show every alert with a customized title.

I already follow the ionic tutorial link [http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/), but it teaches how to change just a specific alert.

I have to change every alert, even those will be showed by code inside a dinamic iframe. Is it possible to do that? How can I do this? I already changed every alert I could, but I couldn't find how to change every alert.

Ionic CLI: 4.0.6
Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 3.7.1
@ionic/app-scripts: 3.0.1

Cordova CLI 7.1.0

It below works fine but just for one alert. I have to edit every alert title to "customTitle" but I can't find how to do that!

```html
let alert = this.alertCreate({
  title: 'customtitle',
  message: 'custommessage',
  buttons: ['ok'],
  cssClass: 'alertCustomCss',
});

alert.present();
```

Comment: Do you mean to change default style for all alerts?

Comment: Yes but also the TITTLE of all alerts, and not just style them...

Comment: You cant define a title which will automatically get displayed on all alerts. You have to set "title:" every time you want to display an alert with a title. No matter its the same title like in all other alerts. Same goes with custom Styles. You have to set "cssClass" every time you want to display an alert with a custom css no matter all others have the same. EDIT: Maybe you could force an Alert to set the same title and class every time you call one by overwriting it in the AlertComponent of Ionic. But Im really not sure if this is a good idea.